# React.js: How to add an item to the card?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react.js and trying to implement basic **add to cart** functionality trying to keep it simple, just to understand the flow. 
I have two cards, in one of them are listed the items, and after selecting the item and clicking the button the corresponding item should appear in the another card.
As far as I understand I need to somehow filter and check if the unique property has a match with the parameter, add to the card.

Please, find the [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/imgmediacard-material-demo-forked-vnwfb?file=/demo.tsx) and the code below

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const StyledBox = styled("div")({
  paddingRight: "70px",
  paddingLeft: "70px",
  boxShadow: "rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px",
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  border: "1px solid black",
  minHeight: "200px"
});

const AddToCard = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, []);

  
  const addToCardHandleClick = (id) => {
    setData(
      data.map((item: any) => {
        const tempItem = data.find((item: any) => item === id);
        if (!tempItem) return [...item, { id }];
      })
    );
  };



  return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 700, minHeight: "300px" }}>
      <CardContent>
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            gap: "30px",
            justifyContent: "center",
            overflow: "auto"
          }}
        >
          <StyledBox sx={{ minWidth: "100px" }}></StyledBox>//The selected item should appear here after clicking
          <Box
            sx={{
              alignSelf: "center",
              gap: "10px"
            }}
          >
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
           onClick={() => addToCardHandleClick(null)} //instead of null should be correct property
            >
              Move
            </Button>
          </Box>
          <StyledBox>
            {data &&
              data.map((item) => (
                <ul key={item.id} style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
                  <li>{item.name}</li>
                </ul>
              ))}
          </StyledBox>
        </Box>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};
export default AddToCard;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you should use a select field for the items. then use the event for the selected item. with an LI you cannot select any items and have no event for them

Comment: Hi @Michael thanks for the answer. Is it the only way to get the value?

Comment: You can set a click event on the LI to keep track of the element that will be moved by adding the corresponding id to a state variable. That state variable can then be used inside the addToCardHandleClick function

Comment: Hi @KossiD.T.S. thanks for the answer. I'll try to get the value of the selected element at least

Comment: I think a simpler solution would be to add a key to the items of data  - let say `data = [{id: 1 ,...}, {id: 2, moved: true, ...}, {id: 3, moved: true,...}, ...]`. 
This means on click on a LI element just set the key moved = true on the corresponding item. Now you can display elements that are not moved using: `data.filter(item => item.moved !== true).map( ... )` and the moved items can be displayed as `data.filter(item => item.moved === true).map( ... )`

Comment: @KossiD.T.S. I am not sure about your solution. Could you, please, show it in action?

Comment: @user17366197
 ill just add, that you should try using valid html. Setting a clickEvent on a custom element should only be done if needed, this is a classic selectbox element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try it in the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/imgmediacard-material-demo-forked-9nq22

I use `item.selected` to keep track of clicked element and once you click on move I drop the `item.selected` property and add `item.moved = true` instead...

If you need to make the moved items appear in the right order, you can either:

- Add `item.order = ++counter` or `item.order = Date.now()` and sort all item.moved by item.order
- Use a separete array for moved items